# Namespace Error -> using com.demo & using System.Collection.Generic

Tags: c#, reference

If i want to run my program i get this error messages from this code part:

```
using System.Collection.Generic;
using com.demo;
```

Error Message:
**The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Error Message:**The type or namespace name 'Collection' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Is there anything to add (references)? If yes what?
Can you help in some way? Thank ahead.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a namespace called **"com.demo"** ?

Comment: If 'com.demo' is a namespace that exists in another project then you'll need to add a reference to that project.

Comment: Also check what references you've currently got e.g. System, System.Data etc

Comment: @ sr28 https://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-cc-application-with-matlab-code-1.html i have this code from this page

Comment: The post suggests to add few assembly references namely `makeSqr.dll` and `MWArray.dll`. Either of these two will contain this `com.demo` namespace. Please read the steps carefully. For the second error the correct namespace is `System.Collections.Generic`. You are missing `s` in `Collections` in the using statement you have written at the top of your code file. It should be `using System.Collections.Generic;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct typo

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Add reference to the DLL having this namespace first. Then

```
using com.demo;
```